# SOLR MoreLikeThis + join query

Tags: solr

I'm using SOLR MoreLikeThis feature to get similar documents based on the provided DocumentID. Would it be possible somehow specify to remove documents that don't have some attribute as provided DocumentID?

For example: document has id, location, ...
query would be: return me documents similar to doc_id and having same location?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be using join query in fq and it works for MLT as well.
Something like:

> &fq=(!join from=location to=location)DocumentID:1234